# Aggregate multiple S3 files into one file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I enabled a Firehose stream to write data to S3. Firehose puts data into S3 file at [max interval of 900s](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-configure.html#buffer). This means around 100 files will be created within one day, which is an overhead for users to manually download.

Is there a solution to automatically aggregate multiple S3 files into one file at certain frequency (such as daily)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no auto-of-the box service for that as this is a use-case specific problem. However, in AWS blog titled

- [Efficient Amazon S3 Object Concatenation Using the AWS SDK for Ruby](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/efficient-amazon-s3-object-concatenation-using-the-aws-sdk-for-ruby/)

they provide some guideline on how to do it effectively. In this blog they say that you could treat those files as **parts of multi-upload** and have S3 join them automatically for you.

I am not sure if this solution is applicable to your use-case, but its probably worth considering.

Otherwise, you have to download these objects, join them yourself (e.g. zip them), and re-upload joined folder. This could be automated, e.g. using instance or container that you run automatically once a day.